# How do I tell OSX to use matplotlib from brew, rather than default?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, homebrew

I have OSX 10.9.5 and installed matplotlib via brew, but apparently there was a bundled version too.
The version from brew is 1.4.2 and the bundled version is 1.1.1, and when I `import matplotlib` I get 1.1.1.
I'm a python beginner, how do I get it to use the brew (1.4.2) version?

Comment: Is your python also installed via brew? if not you might want to install through there and make sure the path is set correctly.

Comment: that clue lead me to the solution, this is what solved it. `brew rm python` then `brew rm matplotlib` then `brew install python` then `brew install matplotlib`. thank you. if you want to submit an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how python environment works, both python and matplotlib need to be installed via homebrew on OS X. After installing make sure your python in path is set to the one installed via brew.

Remove the python and matplotlib in case they are installed via brew:

```
 brew rm python; brew rm matplotlib
```

Reinstall python and matplotlib:

```
 brew install python; brew install matplotlib
```